# Make regex to match in a lazy manner while skipping some words

Tags: regex

I want the regex, which includes skipping some words to match in a lazy manner. For example:
Regex:

```
all(\s+\S+){0,10}\s+(Damages|amount)(?!(\s+\S+){0,10}\s+in\s*excess\s*of)
```

Sample Text:

> all such Damages under Section 8.1(a) in excess of the Deductible
>   Amount

My goal is that I don't want to match if the words **all damages or all amount** are followed by **"in excess of"** and match otherwise. What happens is that this part of regex **`all(\s*\S*){0,10}\s+(Damages|amount)`** matches from the first word **"all"** to the last **amount** word occurrence, which skips the part **"in access of"** to match for the negative look ahead and the match is successful. I want this part of the regex to stop matching further after the first occurrence of word **damages|amount** appears so it can find **"in access of"** afterwards.

Comment: Try `all(?!(?:\s+\S+){0,8}\s+in\s+excess\s+of)(\s+\S+){0,10}\s+(Damages|amount)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ylfaLF/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
all(?!(?:\s+\S+){0,7}\s+in\s+excess\s+of)(\s+\S+){0,10}\s+(Damages|amount)
```

The lookahead after `all` will make sure there is no match if there is `in excess of` within the ten (10 - 3 is 7, hence `{0,7}`) words after `all`.

**Details**

- `all` - a literal substring
- `(?!(?:\s+\S+){0,7}\s+in\s+excess\s+of)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0 to 7 repetitions of 1 or more whitespaces followed with 1 or more non-whitespaces followed with `in excess of` substring
- `(\s+\S+){0,10}` - 0 to 10 repetitions of 1 or more whitespaces followed with 1 or more non-whitespaces
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(Damages|amount)` - `Damages` or `amount` substring.