# modifying regex so that it finds space and put minimum length restriction

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I currently have the following regex

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))(?:\+62|08)\S+\b
```

the issue is that it can't find texts like

```
0823 2371 2318
```

or

```
+62812 2712 2819
```

basically what follows 08 or +62 can be a number from 0-9 or a single space or a dot or an _
I also need to restrict such that it needs to find 10 characters or more

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)(?:\+62|08)(?=[\d\s._]{8})\d+(?:[\s._]\d+)*\b`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7QJb4/1). BTW, what do you mean by a *character* here? Any or just digit?

Comment: 10 characters , I mean any 0-9 or a single space or a dot or an _

Comment: Ok, so the initial plus is not counted. Then it should work for you.

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)(?:\+62|08)(?:[. _]?\d){10,}`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/82DONs/2

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(?:\+62|08)[\s._-]?(?=[\d\s._-]{8})\d+(?:[\s._-]\d+)*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7QJb4/3)

**Details**

- `(?:\+62|08)` - `+62` or `08`
- `[\s._-]?` - a whitespace, `.`, `_` or `-`
- `(?=[\d\s._-]{8})` - there must be 8 digits/whitespaces/dots/hyphens or underscores immediately to the right of the current location
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[\s._-]\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a whitespace/dot/underscore/hyphens and then 1+ digits
- `\b` - word boundary.

If you need to restrict it to match substrings with only 10 digits or more, replace the `(?=[\d\s._-]{8})` lookahead with `(?=(?:[\s._-]*\d){8})`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7QJb4/4), or use `(?:\+62|08)(?:[\s._-]*\d){8,}\b` [regex](https://regex101.com/r/k7QJb4/5).

Comment: the only problem with this is that it does not find strings like WA:085376990877 or WA:+6285376990877 , where for some reason it's appended or hubungi:085376990877

Comment: also this string isn't matched Whatsapp :+62 822-5286-0991 . My current revision based on your answer looks like this (?:\+62|08)(?=[\d\s._-]{8})\d+(?:[\s._-]\d+)*\b

Comment: @aherlambang If you want to match the text after any nonword char, not just whitespace, you really do not need `(?<!\S)`, you may use `(?<!\w)`. Or, as in your current revision, just remove the lookbehind. I suggest trying the other patterns at the bottom of the answer: it may make more sense to stick to digit number restriction rather than all those separators.

Comment: @aherlambang See my updated answer. You should have mentioned you also have hyphens in between numbers.

Comment: @aherlambang  Can I ask you a favor? Someone has just downvoted two good working accepted answers of mine, can you please offset [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55809771/3832970) with an upvote? Thank you. (Just upvote this comment if you read it).

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/FQZdwF/1) divides your input phone numbers into three groups and it might match your desired patterns in an input string:

```
(\+62|08)([0-9]+)(\s[0-9]{4})+
```

[image]

You can simply add other boundaries other than `+62` or `08` to those groups, if you wish.

---

Edit: I'm not sure if this would cover your input samples. You could maybe modify it using a RegEx such as [this one](https://regex101.com/r/qFHdp3/1/):

```
(\+62|08)([0-9\.\-\s\_]{3,14})
```

[image]

Comment: Emma, you are not answering the question. OP wants to set a specific length restriction to qualify a substring for a match. It is nice you are learning regex through answering on SO, but please answer the questions asked.